Firebase Cloud Messaging - FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken() throwing unknown error
I am busy trying to set up push notifications in my Flutter app using the cloud messaging service from Firebase
I am following the a Udemy lecture (if you have a Udemy subscription you can find it here) and have stumbled across an error that I can't seem to find replicated anywhere else online. The code that I am using to retrieve the FCM registration token is as follows:
void _setupPushNotifications() async {
    try {
      
      final fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
      final settings = await fcm.requestPermission();
      print(settings.authorizationStatus);
      final token = await fcm.getToken();
      print('token is: $token');
 
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      print('Error setting up push notifications: $e');
      print(stackTrace);
    }
  }
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    _setupPushNotifications();
    super.initState();
  }

This is exactly the same as it is done in the lecture, and this same code can be found in many examples/tutorials online and in the documentation. However, when I call fcm.getToken(), I unfortunately get an error with very little detail. The result in the debug console of the print statements, error, and stack trace can be seen below:
Restarted application in 308ms.
flutter: AuthorizationStatus.authorized
flutter: Error setting up push notifications: [firebase_messaging/unknown] An unknown error has occurred.
flutter: #0 StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
#1 MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18) platform_channel.dart:334
<asynchronous suspension>
#2 MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:534:43) platform_channel.dart:534
<asynchronous suspension>
#3 MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:248:11) method_channel_messaging.dart:248
<asynchronous suspension>
#4 _ChatScreenState._setupPushNotifications (package:chat_app/screens/chat.dart:20:21) chat.dart:20
<asynchronous suspension>

So as you can see the request is authorized just fine and everything works up until that point, but as soon as I try to use the getToken() method, an error is immediately thrown.
I have tried searching online to figure out why this might be. This stack overflow post led me to have a look at my iOS key in my Google Cloud Console, where I noticed that the Firebase Cloud Messaging API had not been selected for this key. However, after having selected this, saved, and waited much more than the suggested 5 minutes, it did not seem to make any difference.
I have also restarted my app, tried a different IOS simulator, and run flutter clean and flutter doctor. I don't really see where else to go from here as there is so little information on what the error could be.

Today i start catch this error to. I can fine the solution.

See this issue on github.

I see. It looks like this is some sort of bug that has cropped up in the last few days. There is a temporary solution posted on that thread, which you can view here.

This issue now has an active pull request that should resolve it, and so I will close it here. For any updates it will be best to check this thread.

Enable push notifications capabilities through xcode.

Open your project on xcode
In project navigator select your project
In project editor select target then go to Signing & Capabilities tab



Click + Capabilities
Search for Push Notifications then add it
Try to run again.

Reference: Enable push notifications - Xcode Help

Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, this is something that I already did before posting this question. Everything is set up for push notifications as per the apple and firebase documentation.

Ah sorry for that, did you already tried in android and how it works?

Have you tried on iOS physical device? Because I have same issue but it's only happened on Simulator.
Probably related with firebase flutter docs.

Notifications are not shown on simulator but getting a token should work.

are you sure you got the token? as I know, to get a FCM token, firstly need to get APNS token which cannot be retrieved on simulator. so basically you cannot get FCM token on simulator, CMIIW.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
